# My object doesn't show in camera mode

Tags: camera

[[image: before camera view]

[image: in camera veiew]

Hi, i'm having to make a scene for a project at uni and i'm building a castle with the intention of having the camera float around it for an animation like a guided tour. I can edit it fine and all, and i'm currently trying to add a texture to it, when i try and check to see if it has worked and use camera view nothing shows and just shows me a grey screen as if there is no object. I'm using a plugin to build the walls but that shouldn't make them seem "transparent" if i've added a texture to them? I have a lamp set up and have turned it up really high because it's a large object so it's not like it's hiding in pitch black.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does my object not show up?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/67490/why-does-my-object-not-show-up)

Comment: I would start checking viewport clipping settings (N key, properties)

Answer (score 4):

Maybe it's outside of the cameras clipping plane. Select the camera, then go to the camera settings in Properties > Object data. There you can see Clipping start and End. You want to increase the End value so the distance to your object falls within it.

Comment: Don't forget to mark your question as answered then ;)